# reinterpret_cast void* to interface

Tags: c++

Из-за специфики проекта (используется JNI) требуется кастить указатель `void*` в `IInteface*`. (вернее, не void*, а 64-битное число [jlong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html), но не суть)

Пока это вроде работает. Знаю, что если использовать множественное наследование, и этот интерфейс не будет первым в списке наследования, программа упадет.

Какие еще могут быть подводные камни?

Ну а как получить правильный указатель, не зная конкретного наследника?

Компилятор `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.9`

Comment: Ваш вопрос содержит UB почти в каждом предложении, решение вопроса может быть только для какого-то компилятора, а не C++ в целом. Поэтому рекомендую указать все параметры среды, в которой Вы работаете.

Comment: @ixSci Компилятор `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.9`

Comment: @ixSci разве `reinterpret_cast` указателя в число достаточного размера дает UB? Насколько я помню, это разрешенная операция, если тип указателя правильный (не нарушает strict aliasing rule).

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну насчёт «каждого предложения», я конечно погорячился. Я имел ввиду, что преобразование из непонятно откуда взявшегося `void*` в правильный интерфейс потребуют знания расположения подобъектов в объекте, а это стандартом не регламентируется.

Comment: @ixSci слово JNI подразумевает, что этот void* взялся не "непонятно откуда" - а был ранее получен из нашего же кода. То есть объект создается, передается в код на Java, принимается из этого кода обратно и надо им воспользоваться. Разумеется, Java знать не знает ни про какие указатели - поэтому указатель надо временно преобразовать к числу, а потом вернуть обратно. Нормальная ситуация, именно для которой преобразование чисел в указатели и прописали в стандарте языка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С множественным наследованием все просто. Надо, чтобы все преобразования были взаимно-обратными! Если вы берете указатель на интерфейс и преобразуете его в число - то и обратное преобразование будет корректным. Если же вы берете указатель на объект, преобразуете его в число - а потом результат преобразуете в интерфейс - разумеется, все упадет.

Других подводных камней нет, если соблюдать взаимно-обратность операций.

Comment: Да, думаю стоит обернуть указатель на конкретный наследник в некую структуру, где хранить также и указатель на интерфейс, и уже кастить указатель на эту структуру. Правда придется возиться с выделением памяти.

Comment: @zenden2k, не нужно. Вам же нужен только интерфейс - зачем вам еще и указатель на наследника?

Comment: А если понадобится еще какой-то интерфейс того же объекта? Заводить `IUnknown` и `QueryInterface()`?

Comment: @zenden2k это уже недостаток архитектуры приложения. В идеале такая ситуация вообще не должна возникать. Но если все же возникнет - в C++ есть такая вещь как dynamic_cast